# How to create VM's for 32-bit and 64-bit Wine-based development environments on a 64-bit box?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, lxc

I am running a 64-bit Linux (Devuan) and want to create separate VM's to contain Wine as 64-bit and 32-bit respectively, as well as the needed development(coding/IDE/debug) tools for each.

My options:

1. LXC; can this be done using LXC, and if so where can I find guides to do it? (Googling delivers a mess of at times contradictory info)
2. Qemu/KVM: where can I find guides to do it? will this be optimal for resource usage?
3. Virtualbox - do-able but not ideal (space/duplications/optimal?/..)
4. ?

Which option should I use, and where will I find the needed info to implement the option?
(the jackpot would of course be a noddy-guide :)

Comment: This sounds a bit oversized. Did you consider using WINEPREFIX instead? WINEPREFIX is the tool of choice to separate 32 and 64 bit wine installations.

Answer (score 1):

Just use WINEPREFIX to separate your installations. Everytime you start any wine program, do it like this for 32 bit:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine <your program>
```

and like this for 64 bit:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 wine <your program>
```

That should be everything you need.

You may set these env vars globally using:

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32
export WINEARCH=win32
```

Comment: need vm's since the tools i'm developing has the potential to mess things up & i need to protect my base os against that - thx anyway for the suggestion

Comment: if your tools are windows tools that run in wine then they don't have the permission to mess with the system. They are contained in the Wine-Prefix.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, Ubuntu, and Mint Linux, or Windows you can use "virtualbox"

**Install virtualbox (Linux)**

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install virtualbox

Next install the 32 and 64 bit Debian or Windows VMs - as needed

- https://medium.com/platform-engineer/how-to-install-debian-linux-on-virtualbox-with-guest-additions-778afa0ee7e0

If you use docker engine - do not overlook DockerHub images:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/tianon/wine
- https://hub.docker.com/r/thawsystems/wine-stable

Comment: i may end-up going the virtualbox route, would however prefer a 'pure' linux solution: lxc, qemu/kvm ...